# Asus X751SA running Windows 10 Pro

Tags: laptop, bios, asus

The laptop above has been working normally ever since I bought it,however when I turned it on yesterday it went straight to the BIOS login page. I cannot do anything else with the p.c and have NO idea what the password is and I simply have no clue what I can do. Any ideas?

Comment: Your documentation should explain what the default password is.  Once you sort that out, you may find the drive is defective (hardware error) which is why you landed in BIOS in the first place here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will help: You may have to clear your CMOS. It's not the same from laptop to laptop, so you have to read your laptop's manual and find where the CMOS button is (inside your laptop). If you wanna be 100% sure, contact with the company. Now...the BIOS password is either your windows login password, or your password from your Microsoft account you've made, when you bought the laptop. Try those two passwords, but it's probably your Microsoft account password.